# Jquery not connecting to .php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having some trouble with my jquery. I am not sure if it is connecting to doc.php but I am not getting anything inserted into my database.

I have an insert command in doc.php which I know is working.

I'm trying to create a way to update prices in a database, from doc.php, that searches out items one at a time.

The doc.php is searching by var, then updating in the same page.

The foreach loop function then, takes the var one by one, sends them to the doc.php page that then searches by var and updates into the database.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("", "", "") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("") or die (mysql_error());


$sql = "SELECT var FROM table";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {


$variable = array($result['var']);

foreach ($variable as $variable1) {


?>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    var valueToSend = '<?php echo $variable1; ?>';

$.ajax({
    url: "doc.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: { Variable: valueToSend },
    success: function (m) {
        alert(m);
    },
    error: function (e) {
      alert("Something went wrong ...: "+e.message);
    },
  }); /* end ajax*/
  e.preventDefault();
});
</script>

<?php


}


}

?>
```

Comment: Wait, why are you using AJAX for this? If your PHP code has access to the values you're trying to insert, why do you need AJAX if you can just use plain PHP for this?

Comment: There is a lot to correct here. You are selecting values from your database, then cycling through and outputting a custom chunk of JavaScript for each (including a new reference to the jQuery library), which in turn tries to fire off an asynchronous POST to doc.php...why?

Comment: Return anything from your doc.php ... even a parse error would be good enough to find out if the php script got called. Open firebug to see the returned header/output.

Comment: Oh sorry I should of been more clear. I have updated my original post with more information.

Comment: it doesn't seem like you know what your code is doing here at all. you are sending so many messages back and forth to and from the client page when absolutely none of that is necessary. You can do all of this using PHP without involving javascript at all while at the same time making the code 100x simpler and better performing.

Comment: Really?! How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what do you want to do with this code? If you want to read & write to db using php, ajax call is unnecessary. If you want to practice ajax & php you need to read some howto because your code is somewhere strange ;). [This is nice collection of tutorials for jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/) and [some for PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/) read some and practice.

Comment: Here is a link to my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458174/using-foreach-loop-to-send-vars-to-another-php-page                This should explain what I am trying to do and why I am using jQuery.

Comment: Ok i read your previous question. Do you have access to api.php file? If so, better put all logic in this file (maybe use require_once to include it from another file for logic separation). If you want necessarily to post your data better see curl php function. With it you can send post data without forms.

Comment: Fantastic, this seems to be working much better, and easier. Although I cant quite get the variable format down from this example: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3"); Would the logical replacement be something like "$_POST['var']=$var"); but that isn't quite working, so I must have the formatting mixed up here. Anyway, I'll continue to look into it. Thanks again!